# Applescript Alarm Run at Specific Time and Say Temperature

Tags: html, applescript

I've written some applescript to wake me up in the mornings ([here](http://pastebin.com/4DvNpfuL)), and it works fine, however, I want to add some functionality. I want the script to access [this](http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=-31.953005,115.857468) webpage, and tell me the current temperature. Now below is the element for the temperature on the above website.

```
 <span id="rapidtemp" class="pwsrt" pwsid="IWESTERN183" pwsunit="metric" pwsvariable="tempf" english="°F" metric="°C" value="71.8">
   <span class="nobr"> <span class="b">22.1</span>&nbsp;°C</span>
 </span>
```

I would like to know how I would define a variable on the applescript side of things, as the temperature stated on this website.

The other thing I wanted to know how to do, is how I could, say run this script when I got to bed, so it waits until 06:00, and then runs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

-Michael

Comment: It is probably easier to connect a server that returns XML data and parse the data with e.g. a command line utility. That should take only a few lines.

Comment: BTW thats a very professional weather site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
set myUrl to "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=-31.953005,115.857468"
set myTemp to text 2 thru -2 of (do shell script "curl " & quoted form of myUrl & " | grep 'span id=\"rapidtemp\"' | grep -Eo '\"[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*\"'")
```

You can use launchd to schedule these events. [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) will help you.

Comment: Okay, I've dont what you said and I was able to get everything working. You can see my edited code [here](http://pastebin.com/tHFNGPK8). Although this isn't the most elegant way of doing it, it was the best I could come up with. Any other ideas would be welcome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @adayzdone is it possible to provide a solution that extracts also the value in celsius (or only)?

Comment: I don't see a celsius number when I load the page.

Comment: If you look at the page source, you can see a sub-element of the Fahrenheit one, is a part that has the Celsius temperature in it, but I don't know how to extract this data.

Comment: @adayzdone Ah ok, may be the result depends on the visitor's country/language-settings. From OP: <span class="nobr"> <span class="b">22.1</span>&nbsp;°C</span> (second line) – anyway, in such a case the current solution is enough and works probably better than extracting a celsius value that may not be there at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I sorted it out if this is still relevant:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    --this is the city code. Search the code for your city on http://weather.yahoo.com/
    set CityCode to 12765838
    --temperature format
    set t_format to "F"
    --voiceover format
    set v_format to "S"
    --say present condition
    set a_format to "Y"

    set IURL to "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20%3D%2012765838&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

    --downloading the file using curl
    set file_content to (do shell script "curl " & IURL)
    --looking for the line with actual condition
    set theText to text ((offset of "yweather:condition" in file_content) + 1) thru -1 of file_content
    set sub_1 to text ((offset of "\"" in theText) + 1) thru -1 of theText

    --today conditions found
    set sub_1a to text ((offset of "text" in sub_1) + 1) thru -1 of sub_1
    set sub_1b to text ((offset of "\"" in sub_1a) + 1) thru -1 of sub_1a
    set actual_condition to text 1 thru ((offset of "\"" in sub_1b) - 1) of sub_1b

    --looking for actual temperature temperature
    set sub_1c to text ((offset of "temp=" in sub_1)) thru -1 of sub_1
    set sub_1d to text ((offset of "\"" in sub_1c) + 1) thru -1 of sub_1c
    set actual_temp to text 1 thru ((offset of "\"" in sub_1d) - 1) of sub_1d

    if t_format is equal to "C" then
        set actual_temp to (5 / 9) * (actual_temp - 32) as integer
    end if

    --looking for today forecast
    set theText to text ((offset of "yweather:forecast" in file_content) + 1) thru -1 of file_content
    set sub_2 to text ((offset of "\"" in theText) + 1) thru -1 of theText

    --maximum and minimum temperatures found
    set today_min_temp to word 19 of sub_2
    set today_max_temp to word 22 of sub_2
    if t_format is equal to "C" then
        set today_min_temp to (5 / 9) * (today_min_temp - 32) as integer
        set today_max_temp to (5 / 9) * (today_max_temp - 32) as integer
    end if

    --looking for today forecast condition (a bit tricky)
    set sub_3 to text ((offset of "text" in sub_2) + 1) thru -1 of sub_2
    set sub_4 to text ((offset of "\"" in sub_3) + 1) thru -1 of sub_3
    set today_forecast to text 1 thru ((offset of "\"" in sub_4) - 1) of sub_4

    --looking for tomorrow forecast
    set sub_5 to text ((offset of "yweather:forecast" in sub_4) + 1) thru -1 of sub_4
    set sub_6 to text ((offset of "\"" in sub_5) + 1) thru -1 of sub_5

    --maximum and minimum temperatures found
    set tomorrow_min_temp to word 19 of sub_6
    set tomorrow_max_temp to word 22 of sub_6
    if t_format is equal to "C" then
        set tomorrow_min_temp to (5 / 9) * (tomorrow_min_temp - 32) as integer
        set tomorrow_max_temp to (5 / 9) * (tomorrow_max_temp - 32) as integer
    end if

    --looking for tomorrow forecast condition (a bit tricky)
    set sub_7 to text ((offset of "text" in sub_6) + 1) thru -1 of sub_6
    set sub_8 to text ((offset of "\"" in sub_7) + 1) thru -1 of sub_7
    set tomorrow_forecast to text 1 thru ((offset of "\"" in sub_8) - 1) of sub_8

    --VoiceOver Section
    set myTime to time string of (current date)
    set myParts to words of myTime
    set mySpeak to (item 1 of myParts) & " " & (item 2 of myParts) & " "

    if a_format is equal to "Y" then
        say "Outside it is, " & actual_condition & ", and " & actual_temp & " degrees "
    end if
    if v_format is equal to "L" then
        say "Today: " & today_forecast & ". Temperature: between " & today_min_temp & " and " & today_max_temp & " degrees. 
    Tomorrow: " & tomorrow_forecast & ". Temperature: between " & today_min_temp & " and " & today_max_temp & " degrees"
    else
        say "Today: " & today_forecast & ", between " & today_min_temp & " , and " & today_max_temp & " degrees. 
     Tomorrow: " & tomorrow_forecast & ", between " & tomorrow_min_temp & " ,and " & tomorrow_max_temp & " degrees"
    end if
end run
```